# Enable C++11 Support on Qt with MinGW or VS2012 Compilers

Tags: c++, regex, qt, c++11

I've just installed QtSDK and i have some problems whem I'm trying to use **regex** functions.

I get this error when compile my program:

```
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This supports currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
```

I have tried to add this on my project file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
```

and

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++0x
```

But I get more other errors. On Code::Blocks regex works fine and is using MinGW too.
So how to use C++11 facilities on QtSDK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .pro file, add the line

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

Comment: It won't work. I get exactly the same error. PS: I've clean project before and run qmake again but nothing.

Comment: @curiosul: And what is the compiler? Does your compiler match that of the Qt SDK?

Comment: I've read on qt forums and qt sdk is with problems and mingw from kit is old. Now I have installed Qt version for VS2012 and works fine.

Comment: My bad, I've reinstalled Windows and Qt and now it works like a Charm.

Answer (score 1):

Do what C.R. said:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

And always after editing the .pro file:

Build -> Clean All.
Build -> Rebuild All.

I can confirm that this method works. I had problems compiling while having vectors defined with initializer lists. After adding this line to my .pro file, it worked.

I'm posting this because I can't comment on other peoples posts.